# Position SVG item relative to text

Tags: svg

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 30" version="1.1">
  <text id="t1" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">Hello World</text>
  <g transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

This gives me hello world and a rectangle. I would like to know how to position my rectangle relative to my text. I thought this would do the trick, but according to my code above the rectangle should sit on top of the text but it does not.

Edit: I tried this but it didn't change anything:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 30" version="1.1">
    <g transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
    </g>
<text id="t1" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">Hello World</text>

  </svg>
```

Comment: Painter's model. Last on top.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry I don't understand. I tried to put the text below the <G> but that made no difference.

Comment: @RobertLongson Updated

Comment: @RobertLongson Oops I didn't indent it

Comment: The text is to the right of the square because it's at an x of 50%. If you decrease the x value it will be drawn over the rect.

Comment: @RobertLongson There is no anchoring happening at all really. If I made the font smaller or bigger the box just sits in a completely different place. The idea was that no matter what size the text, the box would sit in the middle of the text do to X="50%" and text-anchor="middle"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137541/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-jimmy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close to what you want?

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 30" version="1.1">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" />
  <text id="t1" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.3em">Hello World</text>
</svg>
```

The correct value to use for `dy`, to get the text vertically centred, is font specific.  You may have to tweak that value to match whichever font you choose.  In my opinion, it is a more reliable alternative to other solutions like `alignment-baseline` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach you can try! Maybe It will fit for you ...

```css
p {
  font-size: 42px;
}

p>svg {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:none">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="box">
      <g transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0)">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="12" height="12" fill="blue" />
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </svg>
</div>
<p>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#box"></use>
  </svg> Hello World
</p>
```